# SpringBoot Oauth2.0 integration with Azure Ad B2C, session authentication problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a SprignBoot (v3.1.4) Client application using OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code flow, configured to authenticate with custom idp configured on Azure, I am using the `spring-cloud-azure-starter` library with this `config.yaml` configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        b2c:
          enabled: true
          base-uri:  https://<tenant-id>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-id>.onmicrosoft.com/
          credential:
            client-id: <my-client-id>
            client-secret: <my-client-secret>
          login-flow: sign-up-or-sign-in
          logout-success-url: http://localhost:8080/login
          user-flows:
            sign-up-or-sign-in: b2c_my_flow
          reply-url: '{baseUrl}/my_redirect_url'

server:
  forward-headers-strategy: native
```

And this is my security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    private final AadB2cOidcLoginConfigurer configurer;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(AadB2cOidcLoginConfigurer configurer) {
        this.configurer = configurer;
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->

                authorize
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
        );
        http.apply(configurer);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

when I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/` I am redirected to my Azure AD B2C login page as expected. After the authentication has been successful I am redirected to the page "/" but in logs I see this:

```
2023-10-10T11:50:59.731+02:00 DEBUG 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/?continue
2023-10-10T11:50:59.731+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-10-10T11:50:59.735+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1b791dca, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@15ac02d5, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3d033453, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6133e20b, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@f59da34, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4abbe41c, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@6cceb281, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@619c3546, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@7cca31fc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@67b5e613, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@2af9a5ef, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@e795a1d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6e93b0e7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@34f23816, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter@1d944fc0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@49631cfb, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@50ff7063]] (1/1)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.735+02:00 DEBUG 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /?continue
2023-10-10T11:50:59.735+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.735+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.735+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.735+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.735+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (7/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (8/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter (9/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login/oauth2/code/*']
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (10/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (11/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.a.u.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter : Did not render default logout page since request did not match [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]]
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (12/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : No saved request
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (13/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (14/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter (15/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (16/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (17/17)
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@375e5149]
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@375e5149] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@3562c235
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession EDB38D1C5091A540BB851A21712370D8 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-10-10T11:50:59.736+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-10-10T11:50:59.737+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=EDB38D1C5091A540BB851A21712370D8], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-10-10T11:50:59.737+02:00 TRACE 16588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=EDB38D1C5091A540BB851A21712370D8], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
```

in particular `Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession EDB38D1C509XXXX0BB851A21712370D8 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute` suggest that something goes wrong with session management perhaps ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy was not executed by SpringSecurity, subsequently the application goes into a sort of loop with the same way.

I tried to use another approach by removing the Azure libraries and using the classic use with SpringSecurity and Spring Oauth2Client, I had problems with the management of the response containing the access_token which I solved by creating a CustomTokenResponseConverter, but I get the same final issue with session